# drupal 7: showing main menu links to anonymous users 

Tags: views, users

I have successfully enabled the toboggan present login form on access denied (403), however am not sure how i can set my links to be visible to anonymous users. I used views to create the pages and limited access to users with view published content privileges. Problem is if i do not allow anonymous users to view published content in the permissions section the links will not show.

I have tried content access and ACL but they allow anonymous users to view the content. And i can't use the path /?q=user in the text field, titled, Page Not Found 403(access deneid). Any suggestions?

Summary -: I want to show main menu links to pages (e.g. articles) to anonymous users but i want them to be redirected to the log in page when they click the links.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want to show, and what you do not want to show, to your users.

Comment: I want to show main menu links to pages (e.g. articles) to anonymous users but i want them to be redirected to the log in page when they click the links.

Comment: I have posted an answer. :) I think it would be great if you could update the title of the question to better reflect what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to install the Chaos tool suite (ctools) module, and enable the Page Manager module, and go to *admin/structure/pages*

Then we need to wrap whatever we are linking to in a **Page**, handled by the **Page Manager**. Exactly how we do that will differ a little bit depending on what we are linking to. The page manager contains many options, and I cannot describe all of them in detail here. You may want to watch [this video introduction](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager) if you have never seen page manager or panels before. Videos 1 to 3 together are less than 30 minutes, and are likely necessary to make sense of the instructions below.

For **nodes**: Enable the node template.

For **Views**: Click "Add custom page", add the View in that page instead, and save.

For **Module defined pages**: Use [Page manager existing pages](http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) to hand them over to the page manager.

For **Something else entirely**: Comment on the answer and tell me what it is, and I'll add instructions.

Now, in the Page manager interface for the page you enabled/created above do the following

1. Create a variant of type "HTTP response code".
2. Set the response code to 301.
3. Set the path to /user
4. Go to "Selection rules" in the left menu
5. Add "User:role" == "anonymous user"
6. Save